# Where I can see my Transaction Hashes and Mining Addresses in Ubuntu?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, private-blockchain

I created a coinbase and i used that using passphrase whenever i required , i have all addresses regarding coinbase.

Where I can see my Transaction Hashes and Mining Addresses in Ubuntu ??, I created a private blockchain in my machine.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for a **Block explorer** for private chain. Check this repo:

https://github.com/etherparty/explorer

It shall show you the list of the transaction that you mined till now privately. & then can you can check the details for a txn.

Answer (score -1):

In Geth console, you can find your mining address (etherbase) as follows:

```
eth.coinbase
```

Then you can monitor the activity (including mining) of this account from https://etherscan.io/address/0xyouraddress. For testnet: https://testnet.etherscan.io/address/0xyouraddress